# How to check if a string exists in a list in Python?

Tags: python, json, string, list

I have the following JSON data which I received from an API call:

```
[     
       {
        "mediaAlgorithm": "G.722",
        "mediaDirection": "TX",
        "mediaFormat": "---",
        "mediaState": "OPENED",
        "mediaStream": "audioTx",
        "mediaType": "AUDIO",
      },
      {
        "mediaAlgorithm": "G.722",
        "mediaDirection": "RX",
        "mediaFormat": "---",
        "mediaState": "OPENED",
        "mediaStream": "audioRx",
        "mediaType": "AUDIO",
      }
]
```

Using the following code to get the "mediaStream" value as a string, compare this value to a list of strings and print out any values which do not appear in the list:

```
def parse_json_data(json_data):

    my_list = ["audioRx", "audioTx", "videoRx", "videoTx"]

    for media_channel in json_data:
        channel_type = str(media_channel['mediaStream'])

        if channel_type not in my_list:
            print("{0} is not in the list".format(channel_type))
```

Since the "videoRx" and "videoTx" values were not present in the JSON data I would expect that the print statement would be reached twice and print both of these to the user - but the print statements are never executed.

Initially, I thought there was an issue with the syntax "if **string** not in **list**" - however, the following compiles with no errors:

```
if "my_channel" not in my_list:
    print("Not in the list")
```

Is anyone able to explain what is happening here?

Thanks!

Comment: why are you converting to `str` ? It should already be str right? try to print that value. with unicode crap (python 2) you can have surprises.

Comment: `audioRx` and `audioTx` is not in `media_channel`, but they are present in `my_list`, shouldn't you be checking `if channel_type not in media_channel:`?

Comment: your json input format isn't correct. Missing quotes on dict keys.

Comment: The initial return value was in unicode, I converted to string to try see if it would work instead

Comment: @Stu your code has an error `channel_type = str(channel['mediaStream'])` ? Post more code with JSON data to validate.

Comment: Edited to fix JSON format. 
@SonuKumar - updated with correct name too

Comment: cannot reproduce: note that JSON isn't correct yet. Extra commas work with ast.literal_eval, not with JSON. Show us how you're converting your json data to a python dict.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to check which channels aren't mentioned in the json you should traverse my_list not the json_data i.e.

```
def parse_json_data(json_data):

    my_list = ["audioRx", "audioTx", "videoRx", "videoTx"]
    channel_types = [media_channel['mediaStream'] for media_channel in json_data]

    for media_channel in my_list:
        if media_channel not in channel_types:
            print("{0} is not in the list".format(media_channel))
```

Comment: just a minor edit, in the `if condition` it should be `media_channel` and not `channel_type`

Comment: `NameError: name 'channel_type' is not defined`. You need to place `media_channel` inside the print statement

Comment: Your code doesn't do what you want because it can't - it isn't a workaround, the logic I  your code is flawed as you're checking if the items in the json exist in your list and thus don't get the print for things you never check for

Answer (score 0):

First, you may want to check how that `json` string is generated, because it has extra commas after `mediaType` that need to be removed to be a valid `json` string.

Then you can use `any()` to check if the value exists inside the list:

```
import json

json_str = """
    [
           {
            "mediaAlgorithm": "G.722",
            "mediaDirection": "TX",
            "mediaFormat": "---",
            "mediaState": "OPENED",
            "mediaStream": "audioTx",
            "mediaType": "AUDIO"
          },
          {
            "mediaAlgorithm": "G.722",
            "mediaDirection": "RX",
            "mediaFormat": "---",
            "mediaState": "OPENED",
            "mediaStream": "audioRx",
            "mediaType": "AUDIO"
          }
    ]
    """

def parse_json_data(json_data):

    my_list = ["audioRx", "audioTx", "videoRx", "videoTx"]
    channel_types = [media_channel['mediaStream'] for media_channel in json_data]

    for channel_type in my_list:
        if not any(channel_type in x for x in channel_types):
            print("{0} is not in the list".format(channel_type))

json_data = json.loads(json_str)
parse_json_data(json_data)
```

**Outputs:**

```
videoRx is not in the list
videoTx is not in the list
```

Comment: but the values _are_ in the list... your test with `any` is wrong. OP problem is unclear.

Comment: You are right, misread the question. Updated the answer. Thanks.